# closed world reasoner protege

Tags: protege, reasoner

Making an individual to become 'instance' of a class by 'exactly 1  restriction'
doesn't seem to work with default reasoners in protege.
Is there any other way except closure axiom or any closed world reasoner?

Comment: Can you please add a code example displaying what it is you are trying to do ? It it hard to follow on questions without actual examples in them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will not work. Say you have

```
Class: Person
    SubClassOf: name exactly 1 xsd:string

Individual: aPerson
Types: Person
```

the reasoner will not give an inconsistency due to the open world assumption. To "close the world" for `aPerson` you have to tell the reasoner that `aPerson` does not have a name, which you can state as follows:

```
 Individual: aPerson
 Types: Person, name max 0 xsd:string
```

for which the reasoner will give an inconsistency.
See also [this similar SO queston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115438/how-to-force-a-class-to-have-exactly-one-of-a-given-property/48119222#48119222).