# How to restrict class that its data property assertion must to be filled with OWL?

Tags: owl

I have "User" class, "username" data property, an individual "user1", and i tell "user1" is a "User".

Then i want to tell "User Equal Class" that when there's no "username assertion" on user1, its not a "User".

like an user must have username data property assertion to be filled, if not the reasoning should failed.

can i do this with owl ?

[image]

Comment: Not sure but try to set the domain of username as `username min 1 rdfs:Literal`

Comment: See my answer on [a related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115438/how-to-force-a-class-to-have-exactly-one-of-a-given-property/48119222#48119222).